# In Heavy Rain, how do Madison and Jayden ever meet?

Tags: heavy-rain

Warning, spoilers ahoy!

> Near the end of the game, there was a bug in my playthrough where Madison finds out the location of Shaun.  She says to herself "I have to call someone to tell them", and I'm given the option to call Ethan or call Jayden.  The problem is, in my playthrough, **Madison never met Jayden**.  I figured this was just an issue of branching checks gone awry, however I loaned my copy of the game to three other friends, all of whom also had this same bizarre interaction with Madison and Jayden never meeting.

How can you ever get them to meet in the game?

Comment: Same on my side with two different endings! Didn't try all the possible story paths though...

Comment: Same in my playthrough as well. I thought perhaps because Madison was familiar with the case that she would know who the assigned FBI agent was, so she may be able to contact him even though she hadn't met him personally. The game doesn't really make this connection very clear though.

Answer (score 3):

There is no path that allows them to meet.  Jayden learns Madison's name from clues left behind in Paco's room, but the game never explains how Madison knows about Jayden.

Answer (score 2):

> Madison: I know where Shaun Mars is... I've got to call that FBI guy, Jayden... He's the only one I can trust... He'll be able to save him.<sup>[1](http://youtu.be/2mCK19GQe4I?t=4m59s)</sup> (dials)
>
> Jayden: Norman Jayden?
>
> Madison: My name is Madison Paige. **You don't know me—I'm a journalist.** We don't have much time, so listen carefully. Ethan Mars is innocent. The killer's name is Scott Shelby. Shaun Mars is at 852 THEODORE ROOSEVELT ROAD. Have you got all that?
>
> Jayden: Hold on, how did you know...
>
> Madison: Please, I'll explain later. Call my newspaper, the American Tribune. They'll tell you who I am. Please hurry, Shaun Mars may still be alive.<sup>[2](http://youtu.be/_hExgVHDIus?t=3m58s)</sup>

They haven't previously conversed, based on this conversation in "Killer's Place". As Jason said, it's an unexplained plot hole. There is no way to change this, though they *can* meet if busted at Marble Street (during "The Lizard"). Bear in mind, this doesn't affect the story, explanation, or aforementioned "Killer's Place" dialogue.

Between Madison and Jayden's Blue Lagoon scenes, you can sometimes see Madison exiting in the same cutscene where Jayden is entering,<sup>[3](http://youtu.be/aDa9lTp99JQ?t=12s)</sup> but they didn't recognize each other because Jayden wonders why a reporter was at Paco's crime scene in his commentary.<sup>[4](http://youtu.be/aDa9lTp99JQ?t=5m56s)</sup>